# Facebook "like" button fetch wrong data on views

Tags: views, social-network

I am using Drupal 7 with views and [Addthis module](https://drupal.org/project/addthis) for facebook "like" and "share" .

I have add a "like" field to views, so every piece of content has a "like" button.
when a user click on the "Like" button, facebook fetch the wrong data. It can be the picture of different content (e.g. content from the sidebar), it can the user picture instead of the content picture, etc.

How can I fix this? 
Should I use different social module that is more suitable for working with views?

**Update (2/28/2014):**

I spoke with addthis support, and they say I need to add the open-graph for the image. The problem is that I have many images in all the views.
Anyway, I also have the metatag module installed and inside I can define open-graph. When I atried to define the Open Graph image as the image token ([node:field_image]) of the node - nothing change, meaning it doesn't work.
When I tried to add image token to the "views open-graph" -  I didn't find one.
Can someone help me define image open graph to the views output?

Answer (score 0):

Read about og (open-graph) meta tags.
As I know, [metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module supports this kind of meta-tags.

Comment: Can I change the og (open-graph) on the addthis module?

Comment: As I know this functionality are not supported by addthis. But if you install metatag you are able to define images and text you want to be fetched by facebook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In every page I have sidebars that are actually content panes (views) with a lot of content and pictures. When I checked in the metatag module, it seems there is no "Views Token" for image to put in the open graph section. I can't use any "Node token" for the image of the view.. what can I do?

Comment: I don't understand. If you view the node content, your image should be the part of this node and you targets facebook directly to this image. Otherwise you don't know what image user clicks and you not able to target facebook to image that hi likes. 

To sum up:
If like button is part of views, you kick your own ass. So you should first of all point user to content and then gave him ability to like. ;)

Comment: All my site built with content panes Views. on every content panes there is the image field, title field, Addthis field (like button) and more.. All the sidebars (that have a lot of content) and even page that has only one single content (and sidebars) are built with views (content panes). So, you say I am in a serious problem without a solution at all? why the addthis / Like button does not recognize it is part of single view? This module can solve this issue: https://drupal.org/project/metatag_views_overview ?  OR this module: https://drupal.org/project/representative_image ?